# multiplying lists with an external float in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, floating-point

I have a list comprising wages for workers
I want to give them a 50% raise so i want to multiply the list by 1.5
This is my code:

```
wages = [100, 150, 180, 250, 400]
for i in range(0,5):
    print("Previous wage for ", i, "was: ", wages[i])
    wages = [i * 1.5 for i in wages]
    print("New wage for ", i, "is", wages[i])
```

However this is the result i get:

```
Previous wage for  0 was:  100
New wage for  0 is 150.0
Previous wage for  1 was:  225.0
New wage for  1 is 337.5
Previous wage for  2 was:  405.0
New wage for  2 is 607.5
Previous wage for  3 was:  843.75
New wage for  3 is 1265.625
Previous wage for  4 was:  2025.0
New wage for  4 is 3037.5
```

The first wage is correct but then it starts giving results i do not want. Like wage for index[1] should be 150 previous and 225 new....etc

where am i getting it wrong please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are multiplying the entire list by a factor of 1.5 in every iteration of the loop. You can either, change it to only multiply the item at the index you are iterating.

```
wages = [100, 150, 180, 250, 400]
for i in range(len(wages)):
    print("Previous wage for ", i, "was: ", wages[i])
    wages[i] *= 1.5
    print("New wage for ", i, "is", wages[i])
```

Or using the list comprehension once.

```
wages = [100, 150, 180, 250, 400]
new_wages = [wage * 1.5 for wage in wages]
for i in range(len(wages)):
    print("Previous wage for ", i, "was: ", wages[i])
    print("New wage for ", i, "is", new_wages[i])
```

The statement with list comprehension multiplies **all** items in the `wages` list by 1.5, and assigns it to `new_wages`. `new_wages` is `[150.0, 225.0, 270.0, 375.0, 600.0]` after the assignment.

Edit:
As per a comment by @Mad Physicist, you should avoid hardcoding numbers into your code. So instead of having 5 in your `range` function, use `len()` so it works after you add or remove numbers from the list.

Comment: I saw that you posted before I finished mine, but didn't see what it was that you posted. Nice work. Nearly identical answers

Comment: One recommendation: use `len(wages)` instead of `5`.

Comment: @Mad Physicist Thank you for your encouraging comment and great suggestion. I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @SpearAndShield A minor suggestion - use zip() instead of indexing as you are processing equal length lists

Comment: @LancelotduLac The index is required to produce the exact results the OP wants. We could use enumerate(), zip() and tuple unpacking to accomplish the same thing, but I believe it adds too much complexity?

Comment: @SpearAndShield I missed the fact that OP wants the index printed. No idea why he wants that but you're right - keep it simple